# Imroving/Modifying LINQ query

Tags: linq, sorting, group-by

I already have a variable containing some groups. I generated that using the following LINQ query:

```
var historyGroups = from payee in list
                                group payee by payee.Payee.Name into groups
                                orderby groups.Key                                
                                select new {PayeeName = groups.Key, List = groups };
```

Now my historyGroups variable can contain many groups. Each of those groups has a key which is a string and Results View is sorted according to that. Now inside each of those groups there is a **List** corresponding to the key. Inside that **List** there are elements and each one those element is an object of a particular type. One of it's fields is of type System.DateTime. I want to sort this internal **List** by date.

Can anyone help with this? May be modify the above query or a new query on variable historyGroups.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you want to sort on (the payee type definition is missing as well)

```
var historyGroups = from payee in list
    group payee by payee.Payee.Name into groups
    orderby groups.Key                                
    select new {
         PayeeName = groups.Key, 
         List = groups.OrderBy(payee2 => payee2.SomeDateTimeField)
    };
```

Is most straightforward.

If you really want to sort only by date (and not time), use `SomeDateTimeField.Date`.

> Inside that List there are elements and each one those element is an object of a particular type. One of it's fields is of type System.DateTime

This leads me to maybe(?) suspect

```
List = groups.OrderBy(payee2 => payee2.ParticularTypedElement.DateTimeField)
```

Or perhaps even

```
List = groups.OrderBy(payee2 => payee2.ObjectsOfParticularType
      .OfType<DateTime>()
      .FirstOrDefault()
)
```

I hope next time you can clarfy the question a bit better, so we don't have to guess that much (and come up with a confusing answer)

Comment: Thanks sehe for your time and help. But why is orderby groups.key is redundant? I want the final list of groups to be sorted by payee.Payee.Name ! Secondly The List contains a list of objects. And one of the fields of that object is Date. This List also contains the Payee object. Thank you.

Comment: @VVV: You are right about the ordering: GroupBy does not sort by default. (fixed). I think my answer outlines all the techniques you require. If you update your question and show the types you are working with, I can update the answer to solve the explicit question. Till then, good luck!

Comment: Thanks sehe ! Actually I am LINQ beginner ! But your first query (the one with lambda) solved the problem. Yeah actually each of these objects are massive containing multiple fields and each of those fields were an object as well. That's why my wording caused confusion. But thanks for your help. Problem solved :-)